# Filtering queryset by field='SPECIFIC_VAL' else field='ALL'

Tags: django, django-queryset

In my case i have 3 fields which is set dynamically ALL or a specific value.

```
# note im using Q() function
queryset = queryset.filter(
    Q(first_name=query) | Q(last_name=query) & 
    Q(status=dynamic_status) & Q(gender=dynamic_gender) & 
    Q(position=dymanic_position)
)
```

1. `status` may Active/Inactive/All
2. `gender` may Male/Female/All
3. `position` may Position1/Position2/Position3/All

**Note that ALL means a given limited choice of a field.**

How can i filter the ALL instance in a queryset if one of these fields is set to ALL? Should i use `IF ELSE` condition and write multiple queryset filters or there is an elegant approach?

Comment: `if else` condition would be much better, I suppose.

Comment: well that is my alternative though but still searching for an elegant solution if there is any.